# How to implement Angular $cacheFactory within Ionic 1 for session storage

Tags: angularjs, caching, ionic-framework

So like the title suggests I am trying to get my http GET requests to save so that they do not have to query the server every time a user makes a request (within the app session) The server returns a json object but it takes ~1.5 seconds and it gets called quite often, how can I go about caching it? I have already setup http request to cache by adding the config {cache: true} to my http.get request. How would I actually go about importing the cache factory, using the data from it and optimizing my program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement the cachefactory yourself this way

```
var cache = $cacheFactory('appCache');

var data = cache.get(myKey);

if (!data) {
   $http.get(url).then(function(result) {
       data = result;
       cache.put(myKey, data);
    });
}
```